# setTimeout and refresh the page/tab without losing the hashtag

Tags: javascript, loops, google-chrome-extension, reload

I am new to javascript and wrote myself a script

- It is running inside a Chrome extension.
- I am opening a website with a #script at the end of the URL to start the script.
- The extension checks for #script in the URL and then executes a script.
- At the end of the script there is a reload - when the page is reloaded, the script will be run again (endless loop) > Yes, that's what I want!

**The problem:** After the actual script has finished, there should be a 5 second timeout before the page is being reloaded. The timeout is being ignored by the script and the hashtag in the URL is lost after the reload. The loop stops because the hashtag is gone.

**What I tried:**

```
setTimeout(location.reload(true);}, 5000);



window.setTimeout(location.reload(true);}, 5000);



setTimeout(window.open("https://MyLink.com/#script","_self");}, 5000);
```

All of those are somehow executed instantly (without 5 second break) and bring up the page without the hashtag (even the last one) causing the loop to stop.

**Full code inside the content.js:** *(Additionaly on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ey32SzBP)*

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);


    if(window.location.hash=="#script") {


    var oneKeyOnly = true;


    function checkItem() {
    var itemsArray = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges", ];
    var matchingItems = [];
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    for(var y = 0; y < x.length; y++){
        if(itemsArray.indexOf(x[y].getAttribute("data-name")) >= 0){
            var id = x[y].getElementsByClassName("item-checkbox")[0].getAttribute("id");
            matchingItems.push(id);
        }
    }
    return matchingItems;
}


function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function clickButton(val)
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
       if(buttons[i].type == 'submit' && buttons[i].value == val)
       {
           buttons[i].click();
           console.log("Trying to withdraw!");
           break;
       }
    }
}

var result = checkItem();
var lengthOfArray = result.length - 1;

if (oneKeyOnly == true) {
var rand = randomIntFromInterval(0,lengthOfArray);
document.getElementById(result[rand]).checked = true
console.log("Found: " + result[rand]);
}
else {

for(index=0, len = result.length; index < len; ++index) {
    document.getElementById(result[index]).checked = true
    keynr = index + 1;
    console.log("Found " + result.length + " fruits - Selected Nr. " + keynr + "!");
}

}
clickButton("Withdraw selected items");

setTimeout(location.reload(true);}, 5000);


}

    }
    }, 10);
});
```

If anything is unclear, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the reload method in an anonymous function, like this

```
setTimeout((function(){location.reload(true)}), 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried your code and sadly got the exact same result. In general: If I set a timeout of 5 seconds, does the script go on with the rest and call the function after 5 seconds or does the script completely stop and wait, call the function and then go on?

Comment: Checkout this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e3nzvhu/1/).
In general though, the script will continue on with the rest before executing the callback.

Comment: Oh. This explains a lot. Yeah, then it works with your line of code above! Thanks a lot for the explanation and the JSFiddle!